# Magic Mouse 2 on Linux

Tags: fedora, drivers, mouse, apple

I bought apple's new magic mouse one month ago but I can't get it working on Linux correctly. I remember that my old magic mouse used to work fine but the new one is not recognized as such. I believe that Linux loads the mouse as a generic mouse because `lsmod | grep magic` does not return anything.

While I don't care much about its cool multi touch features, I mainly need it to scroll. Right now that does not work at all (the multi touch features sure would be nice though).

Is three a way to tell Linux to use the hid_magicmouse driver for the new one. I don't think the protocol has changed a lot.

If that does not work, where can I report such a bug?

I'm using fedora 23 but I don't think that makes a different because the Linux kernel handles the magic mouse driver (right?)

Answer (score 4):

I too got myself a Magic Mouse 2 about 6 weeks ago. You can teach Linux to recognise the Magic Mouse 2 and load the hid_magicmouse module (as it would for the original Magic Mouse and Trackpad) by modifying the udev and modprobe configs. The touch protocols *have* changed from the MM1 so the MM2 is still just a 2-button device at this time.
In my spare time, I am working on decoding how the driver should set up the MM2 but it is a slow process.
I have documented what I have so far on a Github project at https://github.com/biggreenogre/mm2. I'm working with Ubuntu Trusty but, since this is in the kernel, it should apply to most distros.

Regards,

Drew

Comment: any luck with getting the scrolling to work?

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined to disagree with the theory the protocol hasn't changed much. While it is using bluetooth and that's why some can pair it and it does basic move x, move y, click left, click right the extra functionality including scroll are all proprietary data stream. If you look even in the support.apple forums there is no support for < El Capitan.